# GWT LocalStorage - Storage objects

Tags: json, html, gwt, local-storage, stringify

[This document](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideHtml5Storage) says:

> HTML5 local storage saves data in string form as key-value pairs. If the data you wish to save is not string data, you are responsible for conversion to and from string when using LocalStorage. For proxy classes used with the GWT RequestFactory, you can use RequestFactory#getSerializer() to do string serializing. For non-proxy objects, you could use [JSON stringify and parse](http://www.json.org/js.html).

Can anyone help me to "stringify" an object to save it on a client?
Has GWT some method to do this?

Comment: You mean want to stringify GWT(java) object ??

Comment: i mean what means the guide...
I need to save an object on a client with localstorage, but my object isn't a string.

Answer (score 3):

You can try **gwt-storage** https://github.com/seanchenxi/gwt-storage, its main feature is to store java object in html5 stroage (localstorage/sessionstorage)

Answer (score 0):

You have to Serialize your Objects.
You can store the Payload which is transferad as String in the TransportReceiver (If you are using RequestFacotries):

```
public class CustomTransportReceiver implements TransportReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onTransportSuccess(String payload) {

        //Save payload to LocalStorage

    }

    @Override
    public void onTransportFailure(ServerFailure failure) {
        //Handle Failure

    }

}
```

Create your own RequestTransport:

```
public class AppRequestTransportLocalStorage extends DefaultRequestTransport {
        @Override
    public void send(String payload, TransportReceiver receiver) {
           super.send(payload, new CustomTransportReceiver());
    }
}
```

And where you init you RequestFactory write:

```
requestfactory.initialize(new SimpleEventBus(), new AppRequestTransportLocalStorage());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is official GWT link for [Retrieving JSON Data](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/JSON)

For Example in that tutorial

Use

```
JsonUtils.safeEval(json);
```

You can pass that result to `HTML5`.

Comment: We really need to fix that tutorial: use `JsonUtils.safeEval()` instead of that `asArrayOfStockData` method!

Comment: BTW, I opened an issue to track it: https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=8037 Now maybe you could update you answer ;)

Comment: The fields of my object aren't string, but other objects.
I can send it with json?

Comment: No first you have to made them also into json ..other wise the toStrig will call on them and if you print them it will appear as Objectname@id1234....